# Why doesn't the ocean gradually turn into hydrogen and oxygen gas?

Tags: equilibrium

Maybe I'm wrong about this, but I thought I remembered from high school chemistry that all reactions are in equilibrium. Some equilibria are extremely far to the right or left, so they appear to react 100% or not at all, but even in those reactions there is a *tiny* amount on the unfavored side.

If that's not true, then the answer to this question will be short. But if it is true, then I have a question about the following reaction, and bodies of water like lakes and oceans.

$$
\ce{2H2O (liquid) <=> 2H2 (g) + O2 (g)}
$$

If I remember right, the energy change ($\Delta{H}$ or $\Delta{G}$) in that reaction strongly favors the left side, so water molecules are not breaking apart into gas in large numbers. However, it's a gas on the right side, so I imagine that if a water molecule at the surface of the ocean breaks into gas, those products will escape, and the $\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{O2}$ gas molecules are no longer in physical contact and have no chance to react again.

That makes me think that gradually the ocean would turn into hydrogen and oxygen gas, even if the left side of that equation were favored. That doesn't seem to be happening, so what am I missing? I don't normally think there is hydrogen gas floating around in the air, but perhaps there actually is enough that some of it is colliding with $\ce{O2}$ at the ocean surface and balancing the equilibrium.

Comment: Why would you think H2 wouldn't react with oxygen in atmosphere?

Comment: Because it's a gas that escapes upward. Is there enough H2 gas hanging around at sea level? I'm not a chemist. I see a vote to close the question, but I think it's a decent question from a layman's or beginner chemistry point of view, even if the answer is very basic.

Comment: There's plenty of oxygen upwards. All in all, there isn't really an equilibrium like that, or more precisely it's one of extremely far to one side that you mention.

Comment: H2 and O2, being gases, ***are*** in physical contact and have every chance to react again. Also, the equilibrium is shifted so far to the left that the expression "strongly favors" is not strong enough to do it justice. Had all this not been the case, your concern would be valid.

Comment: Something a bit similar happens on Venus, IIRC, making the planet lose water. It's not a matter of any equilibrium, though.

Comment: I think it's technically correct to say that it this is actually happening, but in such a miniscule amount that it's completely obfuscated by all the other planetary chemical processes going on. But if you're talking spherical cows in a vacuum, yes, if you wait long enough (many, *many* times the age of the Universe), the Earth would dry out by this process.

Comment: This is good thinking but poor followup. I wonder what did happen to all the water that supposedly was on Venus.

Comment: Should I delete the question? Or improve it somehow? It gets downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe I'm wrong about this, but I thought I remembered from high school chemistry that all reactions are in equilibrium. Some equilibria are extremely far to the right or left, so they appear to react 100% or not at all, but even in those reactions there is a tiny amount on the unfavored side.

Yeah, that's true. But the word *extremely* is doing a lot of heavy lifting to make that statement correct. Let's explore just how extreme the situation is.

Before even talking about the equilibrium we should discuss reaction rates. Even if the reaction is not in equilibrium, it may take a very long time to get there. And I'm not talking about "leave it overnight." The Arrhenius equation relates the rate of a reaction to the energy barrier. At standard conditions (25 C), the speed of a reaction is halved for every additional 1.73 kJ/mol of activation energy. Familiar reversible reactions that happen on the hour scale have activation energies less than 100 kJ/mol or so. By contrast, the Gibbs free energy of formation of water is 237 kJ/mol. So the reaction will be *at least* $2^{(237-100)/1.73} = 7 \times 10^{23}$ times slower. Instead of proceeding in hours, it will take quintillions of years, billions of times longer than the age of the universe, to reach equilibrium.

Even allowing for the reaction to reach equilibrium, what is that equilibrium? [LibreText's chemistry book](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_Chemistry_-_The_Central_Science_(Brown_et_al.)/15%3A_Chemical_Equilibrium/15.02%3A_The_Equilibrium_Constant) gives an equilibrium constant of $2.4 \times 10^{47}$ at 500 K. It doesn't state the units, but when the number is that large, any sane unit leads to the same conclusion. Namely, the equilibrium concentration of hydrogen will be very small, parts per quintillion or so.

In summary, maybe there's an equilibrium. But it will take quintillions of years to reach it, and even when it is reached, the quantities of hydrogen will be measured in parts per quintillion. So don't expect it to matter over normal periods of time.